# Group, apply multiple conditions and take duration in R or Python

Tags: python, r, pandas, loops, dplyr

**Objective**

I have a dataset, df, I'd like to take duration based on certain conditions and display output of `Recipient`, `starttime`, `endtime`, `Duration` and `Length`.

**Problem**

I need to first group the message together if the following conditions apply:
if the `Folder == 'out'` OR `drafts`, the `Message == ""`, `Edit == "T"`, and if the contents in the 
Recipient and Length columns are consecutively the same.

Ideally, this would give me group A along with its duration. For example, this first 'block' of data would be labeled 'Group A', would have a start time of `1/2/2020 1:00:01 AM` and an end time of `1/2/2020 1:00:30 AM`.

Furthermore, I would like to 'match' group A with another 'block' of data if the last row of the Subject, Re and Length column matches the other groups Subject, Re and Length on it first row. So the second Group A would have a start time of `1/2/2020 1:02:00 AM` and end time of `1/2/2020 1:02:05 AM`.

```
Subject Re                    Length         Folder      Message   Date                   Edit     
        a@mail.com,b@mail.com 80             out                   1/2/2020 1:00:01 AM     T                               
        a@mail.com,b@mail.com 80             out                   1/2/2020 1:00:05 AM     T                        
hey     a@mail.com,b@mail.com 80             out                   1/2/2020 1:00:10 AM     T                        
hey     a@mail.com,b@mail.com 80             out                   1/2/2020 1:00:15 AM     T                        
hey     a@mail.com,b@mail.com 80             out                   1/2/2020 1:00:30 AM     T 
some
some
some
hey     a@mail.com,b@mail.com 80            draft                  1/2/2020 1:02:00 AM     T                        
hey     a@mail.com,b@mail.com 80            draft                  1/2/2020 1:02:05 AM     T                        
no
no
no
no
hey     a@mail.com,b@mail.com 80             out                   1/2/2020 1:03:10 AM     T                        
hey     a@mail.com,b@mail.com 80             out                   1/2/2020 1:03:20 AM     T
```

**Desired Output**

```
 Start                  End                        Duration          Group  Subject  Length
 1/2/2020 1:00:01 AM    1/2/2020 1:00:30 AM        29                A      hey       80
 1/2/2020 1:02:00 AM    1/2/2020 1:02:05 AM        5                 A      hey       80
 1/2/2020 1:03:10 AM    1/2/2020 1:03:20 AM        10                A      hey       80
```

**dput:**

```
 structure(list(Subject = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
 "hey", "no", "some"), class = "factor"), Recipient = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("", " ", "a@mail.com,b@mail.com"), class = "factor"), 
Length = c(80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, NA, NA, NA, 80L, 80L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 80L, 80L, NA, NA), Folder = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "draft", "out"), class = "factor"), 
Message = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Date = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", 
"1/2/2020 1:00", "1/2/2020 1:02", "1/2/2020 1:03"), class = "factor"), 
Edit = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, 
TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, TRUE, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names =   c(NA, 
  -18L))
```

I am using this, but I wish to KEEP the rows where the Subject is blank, I do not want this filtered out. As we can see from the first couple of rows on this example, although the Subject fields are blank, it should still be included in the first 'block'. When I remove this part:

```
   filter(Subject != '') %>%, I get some errors, should I remove another      part in the code too? (Keep in mind, I still want to display the Subject output).  Any advice is appreciated.





 df1<-df %>% 

 mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 

 mutate_at(c("Subject", "Recipient"), ~if_else(is.na(.), "",      stringr::str_trim(.))) %>%
 filter(Subject != '') %>%
 mutate(Date = as.POSIXct(Date, format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%OS')) %>%
 mutate(cond = Edit & Folder %in% c('out', 'draft') & Message == '') %>% 
 mutate(segment = cumsum(!cond)) %>%
 filter(cond) %>%  


 group_by(Subject, Recipient, Length, segment) %>%
 summarize(Start = min(Date),
        End = max(Date),
        Duration = End - Start) %>%


  mutate(new_group = (Subject   != lag(Subject, 1, "")) *
       (Recipient != lag(Recipient, 1, "")) *
       (Length    != lag(Length, 1, ""))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(group = LETTERS[cumsum(new_group)])
```

Comment: better re-submit the dput data . Even though I fixed the start , it seems there are other issues with it as well

Comment: Your `dput` has some errors. the `Subject` column has only 7 entries, while the rest have 13

Comment: I have fully updated this @Rohit  My apologies

Comment: If you want to keep the rows with blank `Subject` as part of the first block then don't filter it out. Also, don't group by subject.

Comment: Ok @Rojhit, but I tried removing filter(Subject != '') %>%, and it’s giving me some errors. 
I want the output to display the subject contents., so I would have to remove this part too? group_by(Subject ??